# The best way to store a JWT in ruby

Tags: ruby, api, authentication, jwt

I am currently integrating our system, with an external api. I am using httparty to facilitate the integration.

When I do auth with the external-api we are provided with a JWT, is there a best practice for storing this JWT for future requests in ruby?

Comment: Why not store it in a database, if you use one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thew [JWT Ruby Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/jwt) should be your first choice for Ruby implementation. There are a few other Gems. For more information on JWT in general you may refer to the [gem's documentation](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt) or perhaps [here](https://jwt.io/).

Regarding best practice for storing the JWT, it really depends on your use case, but for yours, it sounds like you'd want to use a temporary cache type store such as Redis if you're JWT has a typical expiration time. The ideas is that after authentication, you write the token to a temporary store, which might look like this if you were using Redis.

```
require 'redis'


my_jwt_token = call_some_api_to_get_token

redis = Redis.new (
    :host => 'hostname',
    :port => port,
    :password => 'password')

token_expires_in_seconds = 60 * 60 # set expire 1 hour
redis.set('my_jwt_token', my_jwt_token, ex: token_expires_in_seconds)

my_api_client.call('some_endpoint', jwt_token: redis.get('my_jwt_token"))
```

In my example I'm assuming you have a client object with a call method which takes an endpoint and the options hash. But this should give you a basic idea of an approach here.

Comment: I think the OP asks something else. He receives a JWT but doesn't know where to store it.

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: @BrandonTeixeira see if my updated answer helps.